# Python - Reverse Linked List Issue

Tags: python, reverse

I have been working on the reverse linked list method for a long time and I am trying to understand why it is wrong but I can't seem to get it. The following is my function.

```py
def reverse(self, head):
    if head is None or head.next is None:
        return head

    prev = None
    current = head

    while current is not None:
        temp = current
        current.next = prev
        prev = temp
        current = prev.next

    return prev
```

I thought the above reverse function should work. Example SLL: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None 
My Thought Process:

```
1. Set temp to reference to the current which is the head of the linked list. Thus, temp.val = 1 and temp.next.val = 2. <br>
2. current.next = prev means that the current is now pointing to None. <br>
3. prev = temp means that prev.val = 1 and prev.next.val = 2 <br>
4. current = prev.next means that current.val = 2 and current.next.val = 3 <br>
```

Is my thought process correct? If not, which step is incorrect?
I also searched up the "correct" way of doing this where

```py
while current is not None:
    temp = current.next
    current.next = prev
    prev = current
    current = temp
```

This works but I want to understand why my way of doing it is incorrect. Don't want to memorise blindly and want to understand. Please help thank you ^_^

Comment: Variables hold references to objects, therefore after "temp = current" and "prev = temp" all three variables refer to the same object so that finally "current = prev.next" is same as "current = current.next" is same as "current = prev"

Comment: @MichaelButscher I think I understand what you are saying. Correct me if I am wrong. Basically, when I did the referencing, they are actually pointing to the same object in memory. I was incorrect because I assumed that I made a copy of the current node using `temp = current`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. temp is NOT a copy unless you take extra measures to make it so. You don't need a copy anyway -- try temp = current.next and see if remembering that helps you (since you're about to overwrite current.next)

Comment: @KennyOstrom Thanks Kenny! I understand it now. :)

Comment: Maybe you already know this, but I'll comment for your thought process#2. The ```current.next = prev``` means that you set the ```next``` property(attribute) of the ```current``` object(node) to be the ```prev```. So it's not that the ```current``` points(references) to the ```None```(```prev```).